# Android - Direction Routing by defined coordinates using GPS

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps, routes, gps

Unlike known routes for streets for example in google maps , say if i have my own made diagram of a mall which is related to gps real co-ordinates so for example i have the real gps co-ordinates of the stairs and the elevator and all the stores and generally the mall paths, but i'm not actually using the google maps view ,rather my own made diagram related to real co-ordinates , so what if i got the user co-ordinates inside the mall and i want to guide him how to reach store A for example in the fifth floor from his current position.

For only a mall that i have co-ordinates of almost everything in it , do i need an algorithm such as Dijkstra's Algorithm to draw a line for the user of how he should reach the store he seeks from his origin or is there an easier algorithm to handle this?